# How to create a junction table for three many to many relationship?

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, relationship

I have three tabels named `student`, `question` and `exam`.

`student:`

```sql
create table if not exists user (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
    email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    firstname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    lastname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    birthday DATE ,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    );
```

`exam:`

```sql
create table if not exists exam(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    exam_type ENUM('daily','weekly','monthly','special'),
    exam_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    total_questions int not null,
    total_marks int not null
    )
```

`question:`

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS question(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    subject_id INT NOT NULL ,
    question_text VARCHAR(1000) ,
    option_1 varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
    option_2 varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
    option_3 varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
    option_4 varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
    correct_option ENUM('option_1','option_2','option_3','option_4'),
    subject ENUM('physics','chemistry','math','english'),
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

- A question can be asked in multiple exam.
- A student can appear in multiple exam.
- A exam can be attended by multiple students.

And I need to store the answer given by the `students` for each `question` for every `exam`.
And I have defined my junction table as below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_answer(
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    exam_id INT NOT NULL,
    question_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) references user(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (exam_id) references exam(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (question_id) references question(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE

);
```

Is it ok to have such relationship or is there another better way for this?

Comment: Your description does not contain details. There exists several different schemes, all of them matches your general description, but they describes different practical situations.

Comment: PS: I have updated the question with `create table statement` of `exam`,`student` and `answer`. Did you mean my question doesn't contain that details earlier?

Comment: " I need to store the answer given by the students ". Then where are you storing the answers?

Comment: *A question can be asked in multiple exam.* Does each definite exam contains fixed and definite questions list? If true then does there exists an exams group where the questions list is the same? *A student can appear in multiple exam.* Does the student must answer all exam questions? Does the student may re-answer the question? Does the student may attend the same exam multiple times? PS. These are the most obvious questions about the system. You must answer both these questions and all possible but non-asked questions. We'd know about your system not less than you.